# Adding clause of and/or to if statement in google docs script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to include and/or statement to an if condition in google script. I am new to script and am not able to find a way to do so. Please help

```
if (dateval<>"") and (repval<>"") {condition if true}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can find all the infos on [that subject](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) (and others ) [on this site.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

in your example the answer is

```
if (dateval!="" && repval!="") {do something}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how can i put Or statement?

Comment: see the first link in the [answer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) on comparisons

Answer (score 10):

Logic   Symbol
Or        ||
And       &&
Equal     ==
Not       !=

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score -2):

I tried [Serge insas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855859) and found out that it did not compile.

I messed around, modifying the line as follows:

```
if ((dateval<>"") and (repval<>"")) {condition if true}
```

I finally got this to work. Apparently, it needs the extra parentheses.

Comment: The order in which answers are presented changes over time as votes change. Referring to an answer as "the first" is unclear and might to refer to the wrong answer after some time.